# String variable with limited number of characters

Tags: string, go

Can I create a variable of the type string with a limited number of characters/runes? Something similar to a byte array that only accepts *n* entries?

```
var myByteArray [20]byte
```

Can I even create a custom data type that will only accepts *n* entries?

Comment: "similar to byte array that only accepts n entries" - that's not a byte array, and it can have more than 20 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I even create a custom data type that will only accepts n entries?

You can create a type that contains exactly n entries. That's called an array in Go.

You can make an array of any other data type, including bytes or runes.

Perhaps something like this would be close to what you want:

```golang
type myRuneArray [20]rune
```

However, this does not have an upper limit of 20 runes, rather it *always has 20 runes*. This may or may not be useful for you, depending on your use case.

Comment: thank you. tried this before. main probleme here ist that one can not do basic operations  like 'myRuneArray = "this is my Text"'

Comment: Yes, comparing arrays and slices is more complex than that.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I create a variable of the type string with a limited number of characters/ "Runes"?

No.